# Не понимаю singleton of Borg

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть замечательная реализация синглтона.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock


class Singleton:
    _singltone = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._singltone
        self.lock = Lock()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Singleton()
    b = Singleton()
    print(id(a.lock), id(b.lock), id(Singleton().lock))
```

> 140009961424432 140009961424432 140009961425496

Подскажите, почему при повторном создании объекта, интерпретатор подцепляет уже существующий словарь аргументов (т.е. `id(a.lock) == id (b.lock) is True` ). В то же время, `id(Singleton().lock)` является другим объектом.

---

Замечу, что создаются разные объекты, т.е. `id(a) != id(b)`. Но наборы аргументов вроде бы должны совпадать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас создаётся **три** `Lock()` объекта, которые присваиваются к одной и той же переменной: `self.lock`. Из-за подмены словаря класса, у вас **одна** переменная `self.lock` для всех экземпляров, но в разное время она может ссылаться на **разные** объекты:

```
print(id(a.lock), id(b.lock), id(Singleton().lock), id(a.lock), id(b.lock))
139896476145760 139896476145760 139896472483320 139896472483320 139896472483320
```

Последние три значения одинаковые и отличаются от первых двух.

Создавая, `Singleton()` вы заставляете `self.lock` на другой объект ссылаться. Обратите внимание, всегда значения `a.lock is b.lock`, но после каждого вызова `Singleton.__init__()` новый `Lock()` создаётся и поэтому `id(a.lock)` меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь паттерн Singleton достигается тем, что `__dict__` каждого нового инстанса класса будет ссылаться на одну ту же область памяти `_singleton`. `_singleton` является аттрибутом класса и будет один для всех созданных объектов.

Есть ещё вариант сделать Singleton.

```
class Singleton(object):
   __singleton = None
   def __new__(cls):
      if not cls.__singleton:
        cls.__singleton = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
      return cls.__singleton
```

В этом же примере идентификатор всех инстансов будет одинаковый

```
>>> id(Singleton()), id(Singleton())
(140529287751440, 140529287751440)
```